# Using currency pipe without a symbol

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I'm trying to use this angular pipe but just to get the format, not with add of symbol such as $ and also not a code as USD.

Answer (score 4):

simple: `{{ amountValue | currency:'USD':'' }}` - the empty quotes will ensure suppress the currency and code

complete reference: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe